# Yahoo! Finance stock data gives different result from their graphs online

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I'm downloading stock data directly from Yahoo! Finance.

I compare "Adj Closed" for two dates to get the growth rate.  For example, on 7/20/1987 KO (Coca-Cola) had an adjusted closing value of 1.71, and on 7/1/2013 it had a value of 40.46.  The rate therefore is 2366%; my program gets this correct.  But it doesn't agree with the graph at Yahoo! Finance, and it's easy to see why:  the graph has the 7/20/1987 value at 3.0238.  But why is it different on their graph than in their data?

I get a worse problem when comparing VFINX (an index fund) to ^GSPC (Standard & Poor, which is what it's indexed to).  The graph shows them in lockstep, as they should be, growing around around 400%.  VFINX grows from 16.14 to 156.14 over that period (adjusted closing).  But ^GSPC grows from 302.94 to 1692.39, which gives a very different ratio.

What's wrong with my data?  Am I misinterpreting something, or looking in the wrong place?

Here's ^GSPC.  The last field is Adjusted Closing.
    `7/23/2013  1696.63 1698.78 1691.13 1692.39 3096180000  1692.39`
    `7/1/1987   303.99  304 302.53  302.94  157000000   302.94`
and here's VFINX
    `7/23/2013  156.14  156.14  156.14  156.14  0   156.14`
    `7/1/1987   30.41   30.41   30.41   30.41   0   16.14`

Comment: From the way I understand it, the API is returning you bad data? If so, sounds like you need to talk to Yahoo about that?

Comment: Yes, Yahoo's historical data for KO is wrong in July, 1987 both from their API and in their historical prices web page. The adjusted price is not computed properly, I'm guessing from some extra calculation during display/export of historical data that does not happen internally when their charts are generated. I believe Yahoo's reporting of this same data used to be accurate. You should submit this bug to Yahoo.

Comment: I didn't use Yahoo! Finance ever. but is there a possibility that the prices are in different currency unit.

Comment: Sorry, It seems I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I am leaning toward Joseph Myers's answer.  I can't see any other way for the price on the graph not to match any price on the spreadsheet.

I can't submit the bug to Yahoo!, as they don't provide a way to do this.

I would like to close the question as unanswerable, but I don't know how to do that (or if the community would rather I leave it open).

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the discrepancy is because the graph plots the closing price (adjusted for splits), but you're comparing it to *adjusted price*, which accounts for splits *and* dividends.

None of the columns in the historic dump show closing price, adjusted for splits only.  Think of "adjusted price" as including dividend re-investment.  Example:

```
Jan 12, 2006    $10 (price)
Jan 12, 2006    $2  (dividend)
Jan 13, 2006    $9  (price)
```

One way of looking at this is that between Jan 12 and 13, you lost 10%.  This is what would be shown on the graph, with a little tick to show a dividend happened.

But, a better way of looking at this is to include the value of the dividend.  So, at the end of Jan 12, the $2 dividend was used to "purchase" 0.2 units of stock.  Consequently, on Jan 13 you own 1.2 units at $9, which has a value of  $10.80, an 8% gain from the previous day!

However, saying that today's adjusted price is $10.80 would be confusing since it doesn't match today's *actual* price.  To fix this, just divide all the numbers by 1.2.  This makes Jan 13 go back to $9, but it changes Jan 12 to $8.33.  All the ratios are maintained, and it's a better reflection of the *value* of the share over history.  This is how adjusted price works.

Here's the source: https://ca.help.yahoo.com/kb/finance/historical-prices-adjusted-close-sln2311.html

Comment: If you read how yahoo defines the adjusted close, @Monkey Boson's response is clearly the right answer to this question.  (And Yahoo is indeed giving correct data.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you and Yahoo are not making the same distinction here between *Rate of Interest* and *Compound Average Rate of Return*.

If you have $10, and 10 years later you have $100, the *interest* required to make that $10 into $100 is 100% (100% * $10 * 10Y = $1000).

However, the *Compound Average Rate of Return* in this case is 23.247%. Calculating compound interest is complicated. You may end up with a different value if you assume the cycle started at the end of the month, vs. the beginning.

Since it is a complicated calculation, **two sources might come up with different answers for compound average rate of return**, both being correct under a different set of assumptions.

This tool can help you work with Compound Rate of Return: http://danielstern.ca/calculator/